# Difference b/w anonymous function, lambda function and closures in php 5.4

Tags: php

Can any one explain anonymous function, lambda function and closures in php?
What they function do, and what are there smart uses.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a generic programming topic and not a specific problem with a specific code. Probably fits better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous functions, lambda functions and closures are all the same thing. They allow you to define a function without a specified name. Typically you use this to make code more readable.

```
$first = function ($ar) { return $ar[0] ? $ar : null };
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$first($array);

=> 1
```

Trivial example, but should give you the idea. It's important to note that you would do this rather than define a normal function only if the functionality is not useful anywhere else. If you would use it in many places, you should probably give the function greater scope (like a public function in a util class) to avoid violating DRY.

Closures also allow you to inherit variables from the parent scope.

```
$min = 0;
$max = 10;
$between = function ($v) use ($min, $max) { return $v >= $min and $v <= $max; };
$input = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
$output = array_filter($input, $between);

=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

`array_map()`, `array_reduce()`, and `array_filter()` are a particularly powerful place to use anonymous functions, since they require a function with one argument as an argument.

The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for this has more examples, as does the excellent [blog post](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/17/on-php-5-3-lambda-functions-and-closures) by Fabien Potencier.

Comment: "They allow you to define a function within a function" --- that's not correct.

Comment: They do allow you to define a function within a function. Maybe you don't like the way I describe the purpose? I'll try to word it better. I fixed the first example, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: they do allow indeed. And it's allowed to define an anonymous function in a global scope (not within any function). So I don't see how "within a function" is relevant.

Comment: Now it's even worse :-S Just remove that phrase.